# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'word2number' Error

Tags: python

While installed 'word2number' using command

`from word2number import w2n`

I am getting this error while using Google Colab:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'word2number' Error

May I know how do I solve the error?

Comment: Do you know where `word2number` was installed?  If not, try to figure it out.  Then look at `sys.path`, and see if it's present.

Comment: You need to be clear about the difference between a runtime import and an actual installation of a module

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run

```
!pip install word2number
```

to install the library to Google colab. `import` statements don't install libraries, they load libraries that are already installed (a lot of libraries come pre installed).